# How to detect when a key is pressed in JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to make a function run when a specific key is pressed in JavaScript. For Example, when I press enter, it will run function that does:

```
alert("You pressed enter");
```

Do you use `addEventListener` or what? Thank you!

Comment: Yes `addEventListener` we use. Can we see your code so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcwJ5/)

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which; // some browsers using keyCode,some which
    if(key == 13){
         alert('you press enter on the page');   
    }
});
```

Comment: `var key = e.keyCode || e.which`

Answer (score -1):

You can indeed use addEventListener, but use (for example jQuery) to prevent errors on different browsers.

For a list of keyCodes: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm

```
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        alert("You pressed enter");
    }
});
```

Comment: `keyCode` is not standardized by jQuery, [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) is...